# Sprite Kit SKSpriteNode drawn outside screen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift

GameScene.swift:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    self.player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"player")
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    self.player.size = CGSize(width: self.player.size.width*2, height: self.player.size.height*2)
    self.addChild(self.player)

}
```

GameViewController.swift:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill;

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

On iPhone 4S, the player is drawn on the screen correctly
But once ran on iPhone 5/5s, the player is drawn above the below the screen, only half of the spritenode can be seen

iPhone 4S:
[image]

iPhone 5/5s:   (NOTE: the screenshot size is different, the sprite node is in the correct size, but just not at the right position)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be an issue with your choice of `SKSceneScaleMode`, specifically, it sounds like you may have chosen the resize fill scale mode. Changing this to `SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill` should be enough to fix this.

Comment: @junyi00 If that's what you're already using I'm wrong. Can you edit your post to show how you're presenting the scene?

Comment: aspect fill will cause that issue, aspect fit (letterboxing) is the better choice

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That was my initial thought, but it appears that the sprite is stretched horizontally in the second screenshot. Not sure about this though.

Comment: about that, it its my fault, i didn't take a screenshot with the same size

Comment: @LearnCocos2D aspect fit is working, is there no other way to solve this?

Comment: scalemode resizefill and program your game keeping in mind that there are 88 fewer horizontal points on iphone 4/4s devices. You can change scene anchorpoint to 0.5,0.5 so that the "unsafe" region is 44 points on both sides.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Could u explain further but do so as an answer to his question instead?